# How to disable opening the page in a new tab in Selenium Webdriver in Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am scraping the site : http://www.delhidistrictcourts.nic.in/DLCIS-2016-2.html

There are a number of links in this page. The user would click on any of these links ( via selenium web driver). The problem is, when the user clicks on these links, it opens  in a new tab because all the links has an attribute ( "`_target=blank`")

Any idea how to force, the links to open in the same tab ?

Here is the code I have written

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
url = 'http://www.delhicourts.nic.in/DLCIS-2016-2.html'

driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get(url)

try:
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "submit1"))).click()
except Exception as e:
    print str(e)
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You can try to update the value of `@target`:

```
link = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "CASE NUMBER WISE")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].target='_self';", link)
link.click()
```

To apply the same for all the links on page:

```
links = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.TAG_NAME, "a")))
for link in links:
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].target='_self';", link)
```

or extract `@href` of link and `get()` it:

```
link = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "CASE NUMBER WISE")))
url = link.get_attribute('href')
driver.get(url)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Anderson for your help. `link = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "submit1")))` is a form submission(submit button)  and not a link.

Comment: Yep, but there was no code for link in your question, so... just apply the same for link node

Comment: that is the part of the code I am missing. The user will be selecting from a number of links which takes him to the new tab. This tab has a form for which I have written the code above

Comment: *how to force, the links to open in the same tab?*  presumes that link is already found... Do you need to locate the link or to open it in the same page? Update your question accordingly

Comment: That is correct. I will not know the link because there are a number of links in the URL. Each of these link will take you to a page ( in a new tab). I would need to open the link which the user clicks  in the same page. I will modify the question with additional screenshots